# Hilla app launch error. No valid executable found

Tags: java, vaadin, hilla

Trying to launch the hilla app and getting below error message:

I am trying to launch the application from this github repo: https://github.com/marcushellberg/customer-support-agent

````
dev.hilla.engine.commandrunner.CommandNotFoundException: No valid executable found
    at dev.hilla.engine.commandrunner.CommandRunner.lambda$run$0(CommandRunner.java:72) ~[engine-core-2.2.0.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:403) ~[na:na]
    at dev.hilla.engine.commandrunner.CommandRunner.run(CommandRunner.java:72) ~[engine-core-2.2.0.jar:na]
    at dev.hilla.internal.AbstractTaskEndpointGenerator.prepareEngineConfiguration(AbstractTaskEndpointGenerator.java:87) ~[engine-runtime-2.2.0.jar:na]
    at dev.hilla.internal.AbstractTaskEndpointGenerator.getEngineConfiguration(AbstractTaskEndpointGenerator.java:59) ~[engine-runtime-2.2.0.jar:na]
    at dev.hilla.internal.TaskGenerateOpenAPIImpl.execute(TaskGenerateOpenAPIImpl.java:67) ~[engine-runtime-2.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.NodeTasks.execute(NodeTasks.java:312) ~[flow-server-24.1.11.jar:24.1.11]
    at com.vaadin.base.devserver.startup.DevModeInitializer.runNodeTasks(DevModeInitializer.java:352) ~[vaadin-dev-server-24.1.11.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.base.devserver.startup.DevModeInitializer.lambda$initDevModeHandler$0(DevModeInitializer.java:293) ~[vaadin-dev-server-24.1.11.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1804) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1796) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:387) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1312) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1843) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1808) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:188) ~[na:na]```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get more details about the issue by setting a more detailed log level in `application.properties`, for example:

```
logging.level.dev.hilla=trace
```

But it seems that Maven cannot be found, and I see that the application you're trying to run misses the Maven Wrapper.

Either add the wrapper to the application or make sure your local Maven is available on PATH.

Comment: Thanks, after adding maven to the path issue get resolved.